# Does Mongo's convertToCapped allocate more space every time it's run?

Tags: mongodb, database

I ran

`db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "all", size: 268435456000})`

to cap the current collection at 250GB. The SSH session timed out, but I saw a 250GB increase in disk usage. I checked the logs and saw:

```
Thu Jun 28 23:41:18 [conn312] command logs.$cmd command: { convertToCapped: "all", size: 268435456000.0 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:37 4399826ms
Thu Jun 28 23:41:20 [conn313] end connection 127.0.0.1:53704
```

What's ntoreturn:1?

I ran the command again. I figured it would just see that it was already 250GB and capped, but it's filling up another 250GB. What am I doing exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `convertToCapped`, MongoDB clones the original collection to create a new capped collection with the requested size before deleting the original one. You should see this in the mongod logs with a sequence that roughly looks like:

```
Fri Jun 29 15:14:49 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile ./capped.2, filling with zeroes...
Fri Jun 29 15:14:54 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile ./capped.2, size: 2047MB,  took 4.984 secs
Fri Jun 29 15:14:54 [conn1] command capped.$cmd command: { cloneCollectionAsCapped: "all", toCollection: ".tmp.convertToCapped.all", size: 1536870912.0 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:37 5134ms
Fri Jun 29 15:14:54 [conn1] CMD: drop capped.all
Fri Jun 29 15:14:54 [conn1] command capped.$cmd command: { convertToCapped: "all", size: 1536870912.0 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:37 5135ms
```

- New datafiles are preallocated for the capped collection (called 'all' to match your example)
- The existing collection is cloned to a temporary capped collection
- The original collection is dropped
- The temporary collection is renamed to the original

So if you have a capped collection that is 250Gb and re-run convertToCapped with 250gb you will temporarily double the space used (250Gb for the original capped collection and 250Gb for the new).

You can reclaim the extra space using [db.repairDatabase()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-RecoveringDeletedSpace).